# Post array does not storing file inputs

Tags: php, image, post, input, enctype

I'm facing this strange issue.

I need to upload multiple image with one input. On the input I have a js code that shows me the uploaded image, but when I try to check the $_POST array the image are not submitted.

Half an hour ago it worked well, so I thought it was a cache problem, but even if I empty the cache I cant manage the problem. I cant remember if I changed something, but the code seems to be the same as before (when the code worked).

I work with MAMP on windows 10.

Here is the html (the "form-question" div including the image input is the last one below):

```
  <form action="?mode=dati" method="post" id="dati" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="form-question">
<label for="n2">Nome dell'azienda</label>
<input type="text" id="n2" name="nomeAzienda" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['nomeAzienda']?>">
 </div>
 <div class="form-question">
  <label for="n3">Indirizzo</label>
  <input type="text" id="n3" name="indirizzo" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['indirizzo']?>">
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
   <label for="n3">Cap</label>
   <input type="text" id="n3" name="cap" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cap']?>">
   <label for="n4">Città</label>
   <input type="text" id="n4"name="citta" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['citta']?>">
   <label for="n5">Provincia</label>
   <input type="text" id="n5" name="provincia" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['provincia']?>">
   <label for="n6">P.IVA</label>
   <input type="text" id="n6" name="partitaIva" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['partitaIva']?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-question">
  <label for="n7">Indirizzo email</label>
 <input type="text" name="email" id="n7" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email']?>">
  </div>
 <div class="form-question"> 
    <label for="immagine">Immagine</label>
    <input type="file" name="immagine[]" class="form-control"  
    oninput="immagine_preview.src=window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]); 
    immagine_preview1.src=window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[1]); 
    immagine_preview2.src=window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[2]); " multiple/>
    <img id="immagine_preview" width="100px" height="100px"> 
    <img id="immagine_preview1" width="100px" height="100px"> 
    <img id="immagine_preview2" width="100px" height="100px"> 
   </div>
  <div class="button-wrapper">
  <button type="submit" id="registra">Registra i dati</button>
  <button type="button" id="prosegui" class="disabled">Prosegui</button>
 </div>
 </form>
```

And here is the php:

```
if ( $_GET ) {
 if ( isset( $_GET[ 'id_sondaggio' ] ) || isset( $_GET[ 'mode' ] ) ) {
  $id_sondaggio = $_GET[ 'id_sondaggio' ];
  $mode = $_GET[ 'mode' ];
  }
 }
 if ( $mode == 'dati' ) {
 var_dump($_POST);
    die();
  }
```

I'm not getting what's wrong here. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: You are submitting the form “normally”, yes? Not via AJAX in the background, sending the image data as base64 encoded strings, or any such (popular) nonsense? Well then the uploaded files will of course be in `$_FILES`, not `$_POST` …

Comment: @Cbroe, but the $_POST  usually stores the image input name.

Comment: No, it doesn’t. Only if you don’t set the proper `enctype` on the form - but then you are not performing an actual file upload in the first place, then _only_ the file name does get send (and lands in $_POST, in that situation, yes.)

Comment: @cbroe ok, thank you. So what's your suggestion? Maybe I can add the enctype and then use the $_FILES['immagine']['name'] to get and use the uploaded image url?

Comment: The enctype you currently have already _is_ the correct one for performing a file upload. What is your actual problem, how does $_FILES _not_ contain all the info you need? If you are not sure _what_ you actually received in there - well then make a debug output via var_dump, and check!

Comment: @CBroe it actually contains the name of the image I send, and that's ok. I was very confused because I was checking an old school project where we wrote a similar form, with mixed image and and text input, and only now I recognised that in these old forms we _never_ used the original name of the image retrieved by the $_POST. **thank you**